# A simple and easy checklist for WP7 app to be submitted

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an app coded up and ready to be submitted, but can't seem to find out an easy and simple checklist for submitting apps to the windows marketplace. [This source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) is very lengthy and complicated. I am hoping to generate a simple checklist from the responses here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a brief check list here [Submitting your app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206724%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Also you can Test your app submission from your Visual studio itself my using the [Marketplace Test kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394032%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Update:

According to the modified marketplace requirements, only One 300*300 icon is enough.

Check it in the [4.5 Windows Phone Marketplace Iconography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184844%28v=vs.92%29) section

It says --

```
A tile icon (required), 300 x 300 pixels in size. This icon is automatically
resized for use in Windows Phone Marketplace.
```

Comment: some msdn articles say that the small tile icon size should be `62x62` and some say it should be `99x99`. Similar, issue is there with marketplace icon `300x300` vs `200x200`. Which one is correct ?

Comment: MarketPlace Tile Icon 300x300 And Application Icon 62x62 And Application Tile Icon 173x173. These are the standards using as I am using in my current production app. Submitted few days back and published successfully

Comment: If u check the `Marketplace Test kit`, it asks for `99x99` and `200x200` size. When u submitted your app ?